# Appearance of deleted posts?

Tags: support, deleted-posts

When we delete our answer to someones question it displays deleted by owner. Is this post is visible to others after deleting because I don't want show some code to others because of some reasons?

Comment: If you'd rather not make your deleted contents too visible to the world, edit your post first and then delete, that way one would need to look at the revision history to see it. I don't believe too many people would take an "Oops, stupid mistake, deleting." as an incentive to look at the revisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this post is visible to others after deleting because I don't want show some code to others because of some reasons

Deleted posts are visible to all users having 10k+ rep, if they have a direct URL to the post. All deleted posts are visible to Moderators. If you "don't want to show the code", you should not post them at all

Comment: Ya. I already posted some answer so if I want to delete so asked. :-)